# Logging assembly code execution

Tags: c++, assembly, gdb

I wanted to know if there is a way of logging **just** the **assembly code instructions** that were **executed**. Can this be achieved using GDB?

Comment: Everything in your code is *just the assembly*

Comment: Would be easier to just disassemble the binary… That will give you all of the instructions that were executed. Add *specific* logging code if you need to follow branches, etc.

Comment: [Process Record](https://www.sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/ProcessRecord/Tutorial) is probably the most close to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, it's pretty easy to put the CPU in single-step mode, and log each instruction as it's executed. Practically speaking, you can't reasonably plan on doing this for more than a couple seconds of execution (or something on that general order). Let's work through a bit of the math to understand why.

For the moment, let's assume that a single address occupies 32 bits. Let's assume that a typical instruction uses around 2 bytes of data on average. A typical CPU might run at, say, 2.5 GHz, and execute around 2 instructions per cycle. So, logging a single instruction requires around 6 bytes of data. A CPU executes around 5 billion of those per second. Doing the math, that means logging one second of execution will require around 6 * 5 billion bytes = 30 gigabytes per second (per core).

If we write that to RAM, we can probably expect execution to be something like an order of magnitude slower than normal, so executing and logging one second will require *something* like a few minutes. When we run out of RAM, however, (and at 30 GB/s, we will pretty quickly) and have to write the data to disk instead, our bandwidth (even with a fairly fast SSD) drops quite a bit, so execution speed is going to drop a *lot* more in a big hurry. Likewise, for the moment, I'm (more or less) assuming that we can use (for example) at least one core entirely to collect and log data being generated by one other core. If we want to log data from (say) four cores, data collection will probably slow down some, and (worse) the rate at which data is generated will go up by a factor of 4 as well (so we have one core to collect 120 GB/s). That's obviously going to be a lot more difficult.

From there we run into one other obvious problem: what are we going to do with this *mountain* of data? Given the amount we're producing, it's clearly preferable to do as much processing during execution to find the data we actually care about, rather than just collecting it all, regardless of how useless it might end up being.

All that said, I don't think gdb is really the right tool for this job. If you really insist on doing it (probably a poor idea, but...) you almost certainly want code dedicated specifically to deal with this specific job.